# Espresso test swipes the wrong pager

Tags: android, android-espresso

So I have a wizard with 4 panels, the first one has a DatePicker, which I have in the default Calendar mode.

When this code is run:

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class OnboardActivityTest {

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void onboardActivityTest() {
    ViewInteraction appCompatButton = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.button), withText("Start Setup"),
                    withParent(allOf(withId(R.id.activity_main),
                            withParent(withId(android.R.id.content)))),
                    isDisplayed()));
    appCompatButton.perform(click());

    onView(withId(R.id.onboardingPager)).perform(swipeLeft());
```

the test swipes the calendar left and I get the next month, not the next page.

I had this working before when I had the DatePicker in spinner mode, it was using the pager properly.

The only thing I can think is that it cannot find the pager and so the swipe is just running against the view root?

If I change it back to spinner mode, the page does advance.

Comment: how is the behaviour in your app when you swipe with your finger? can you swipe from everywhere and the viewpager changes or do you have to swipe from the border (outside the picker layout) or otherwise you also swipe the picker?

Comment: I am using the emulator so of course I am click-dragging to make the swipe. But look at the code! I am getting the pager by its ID??

Comment: yeah i think that does not matter very much. espresso performs the swipe on the screen - if there is another view over your pager layout then that view receives the swipe. So the best option imho would be to either select the tab  header if it is displayed or swipe at a location where the picker does not overlay the tab

Comment: Of course I am swiping at a location where the calendar is not appearing.. I am going to add either tabs or a stepper. Was hoping it would be possible from within the new design tool but now pretty convinced it's not. Thanks @stamanuel.

Answer (score 0):

again not sure if it helps (since I dont know how your exact layout looks like): You could try a custom swipe event where you exactly define from where to where the swipe is performed:

```
public static ViewAction customLeftSwipe() {
    return new GeneralSwipeAction(Swipe.FAST, GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
            GeneralLocation.BOTTOM_LEFT, Press.FINGER);
}
```

usage:

```
onView(withId(R.id.onboardingPager)).perform(customLeftSwipe());
```

Comment: Wow cool! Will try this. In the meantime, I have temporarily outsmarted it. I did onView(withId(R.id.<text field above datePicker>)) and it works! (Should have said out dumbed it.)